# Custom email address with Google Apps?

Tags: email, google-workspace

I am very new with web hosting and I'd like to setup a custom email address with my domain for myself specifically *me@domain.com*. I've already purchased the domain but the .TLD does not come with DNS management, so I have opted for paid DNS hosting with the domain name registrar I purchased my domain from.

In Google Apps, I only have the choice of `http://mail.domain.com` and default `http://mail.google.com/a/domain.com`. How then can I do so?

Edit: I've already setup it to my specifications. But when I send a test email to the custom email address, I get this error; The error that the other server returned was:

```
550 550-mail-yx0-f175.google.com [209.85.213.175]:40553 is currently not permitted 550-to relay through this server.
```

Am I correct in assuming I need to wait for the DNS records to propagate with the new MX records, for me to use the email

Answer (score 3):

It's not clear to me if you can manage the DNS of your domain or not. In order to configure your domain to use Google Apps, you must be able to configure your DNS records. In particular, you need to be able to change MX, CNAME and A records.

You can find more here:

- [Set up Google Apps services](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/topic.py?topic=9197)
- [Configuring Your MX Records: Other domain hosts](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?answer=33915)

Comment: No. I cannot change my DNS of my domain. I have to liase with the administrator of my DNS hosting server in order to change the MX, TXT records.

I've already setup it to my specifications. But when I send a test email to the custom email address, I get this error;

The error that the other server returned was: 550 550-mail-yx0-f175.google.com [209.85.213.175]:40553 is currently not permitted
550-to relay through this server.
Am I correct in assuming I need to wait forthe DNS records to propagate with the new MX records, for me to use the email address?

Answer (score 1):

In your DNS hosting you should be able to say that email to `domain.com` should be redirected to `mail.domain.com` by adding an MX record.